# iOS - UITableView Pan Gestures

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

This may turn out to be 2 questions in one, but I believe solving the first will go most of the way to solving the second.

First, I have created a view in Interface Builder (I know!) and I load the xib file into my view controller in the app delegate. All of this runs smoothly and as expected. 
The view consists of 3 table views, two of a similar size and one small one in a corner.
A cell is added to one table view a pan gesture is added to allow movement around the scene.

However, if a cell is moved from it's table view, it appears to go BEHIND the parent view, as per the screenshot below:
[image: Cell dragged between views]

The grey line between the two tables is the gray background of the parent view. If the user still has his/her mitts on the cell, they can drag it into view but how can I make it so that all table views are on the same 'layer'? 
I.e. so that dragging a cell from one table view to another with show the cell hovering over both views.

This leads me onto my second question, which I will not ask yet as I believe the solution to this will solve my current issue. but I will explain for further clarity.
In my pan gesture, I use a point inside check to see if the cell is within a table view, currently panning a cell from any table makes it print. It is almost like the views take up the whole screen, even though they are sized not to?

All ideas welcome! Thanks!

Comment: I guess that the issue should be in your cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: No it is not, the cell is overplayed on top of the tale view and the reference is not to do with the contents of the table then. It seems to be something to do with the transition of the cell from the views.

Comment: However, I cannot catch the event of where the cell has gone as it thinks the cell is in a table view that it is not so it is firing regardless. I can post the code if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by listening for the cell leaving the bounds of the table view, when this happened, I transferred the cell across the table view that it has been dragged to, adding it to the bottom of the list.
Not the most elegant solution and you do lose the touch but it does work,